# How to evaluate a derivative at a given point in Maxima

Tags: math, maxima, derivative

I need to generate in the Maxima software the expression f'(e) - 1, or using other notation, (df/dx)(e) - 1. I'm doing it calculating the derivative of f(x) and then making a substitution:

```
subst(%e, x, diff(f(x), x)) - 1
```

However, I get the following result:

[image]

Does any body know how could I get the correct expression?

Comment: I think you should be able to figure out the solution looking at the documentation http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_18.html and http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_21.html

Answer (score 3):

Use `at` instead of `subst`:

```
at(diff(f(x),x), [x=%e]);
```

Execution yields the desired result.

See the documentation [here](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_18.html).